# use persistent connection to grab data

Tags: php, json

Hi all i am grabbing around 1.3k of record from Steam's database and I am wondering how I can speed up my script.

Currently I use file_get_contents on their API url in a loop for each app's ID (so this is sending 1.3k requests which as you can imagine is painfully slow).

Is there a better way? We used to lump all the app's id's together, but they have removed that ability it seems we have to do it one at a time now, and it's not good.

This is my code showing the loop:

```
foreach($Chunks as $Game)
{
    if ($Game['bundle'] == 0)
    {
        $Subs_URL = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/packagedetails/?packageids=' . $Game['steam_appid'] . 
'&cc=' . $cc . '&filters=basic,price_overview';

        if ($JSON = file_get_contents($Subs_URL))
        {
            $DecodedJson = json_decode($JSON,true);
            foreach($Chunks as $Chunk)
            {
                if (!isset($DecodedJson[$Chunk['steam_appid']]['data']['steam_appid']))
                {
                    $DecodedJson[$Chunk['steam_appid']]['data']['steam_appid'] = $Chunk['steam_appid'];
                }
            }
            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($DecodedJson);

            //print_r(array_keys($DecodedJson));
            $GameList = array_merge($GameList,$DecodedJson);

        }

        else
        {
            die("Steam API timed out!");
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of what $Chunks is:

```
array(1358) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["steam_appid"]=>
    string(6) "227580"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "10,000,000"
    ["dlc"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["bundle"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["steam_appid"]=>
    string(6) "206712"
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "Cities in Motion: Ulm"
    ["dlc"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["bundle"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["steam_appid"]=>
    string(6) "259620"
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "3079 -- Block Action RPG"
    ["dlc"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["bundle"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Comment: You can do it in parallel using the socket API. e.g. socket_select and non-blocking io

Comment: How would you propose I adjust the code I have to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of `$Chunks`? (probably shortened) ... Can provide an example later..

Comment: Updated my question with an example of what Chunks is.

Comment: You may want to use something like Gearman to run many taks in parallel. You could for example run 20 requests at a time with 20 Gearman workers. Since you said Steam removed the ability to query many IDs at once, parallel execution seems to be the only way to speed things up.

Comment: @MartinMüller Gearman is some sort of overkill here

Comment: That's the problem I need examples that would fit with what I'm doing to learn from.

Comment: You can use `curl_multi_exec()` to perform parallel request. Follow this manual: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: Looks a little complicated, and you would need to know exactly how many your opening, mines dynamic based on how many rows are in the database at the time?